# Search for an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

The function must take the make of the car as the second argument. If the `mark` is not found, the message “car sold” should be displayed. If the brand is found, it should show the object of the car you were looking for. What is the mistake?

```js
const arr = [{
    "mark": "BMW",
    "price": "55 000",
    "color": "red",
    "constructor": "Billy%Zekun",
    "country": "Germany",
    "certificate": "yes"
  },
  {
    "mark": "Mercedes-benz",
    "price": "63 000",
    "color": "blue",
    "constructor": "Jon%Adams",
    "country": "Germany",
    "certificate": "yes"
  },
  {
    "mark": "TOYOTA",
    "price": "48 000",
    "color": "blue",
    "constructor": "Jon Hubert",
    "door": "3",
    "max_people": "7",
    "country": "Japan",
    "certificate": "yes"
  },
  {
    "mark": "Volkswagen",
    "price": "36 000",
    "color": "red",
    "constructor": "Pier Sun",
    "country": "Germany",
    "certificate": "no"
  },
];

function car(arr, mark) {
  let carss = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.mark === mark;
  })
  return carss !== mark ? carss[0] : "car sold";
};

console.log(car(arr, "Mercedes-benz", ));
```

Comment: `carss` is an array

Comment: `carss` will be an array. It doesn't make sense to compare it to `mark`

Comment: You might like [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: [How do I create a runnable Stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. You can't compare arrays using `!==` (or `!=`, or `==`, or `===`). Even when they have the same contents, two distinct arrays are never equal to each other.
2. `filter` isn't the right choice for searching an array for a match. In this case, since you want to return the first car found, you'd use `find` (with the same predicate function you have now).

Using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
function car(arr,mark ){
  let car = arr.find(function(item){
     return item.mark === mark ;
  })
  return car || "car sold";
}
```

or you might use an arrow function

```
function car(arr,mark ){
  let car = arr.find(item => item.mark === mark);
  return car || "car sold";
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const arr = [
   {  
     "mark":"BMW",
     "price":"55 000",
     "color":"red",
     "constructor":"Billy%Zekun",
     "country":"Germany",
     "certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
    "mark":"Mercedes-benz",
    "price":"63 000", 
    "color":"blue",
    "constructor":"Jon%Adams",
    "country":"Germany",
    "certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
    "mark":"TOYOTA", 
    "price":"48 000", 
    "color":"blue",
    "constructor":"Jon Hubert",
    "door":"3"  ,
    "max_people":"7",
    "country":"Japan",
    "certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
    "mark":"Volkswagen",
    "price":"36 000", 
    "color":"red",
    "constructor":"Pier Sun",
    "country":"Germany",
    "certificate":"no"
  },
 ];

function car(arr,mark ){
  let car = arr.find(item => item.mark === mark);
  return car || "car sold";
}

console.log(car(arr , "Mercedes-benz"));
```

(You also have an extra `,` in your `console.log` call which I removed in the example. It works because trailing commas are allowed in argument lists in modern JavaScript, but would have failed just a few years ago.)

Comment: ...or you might go ES6: `const car = (arr, mark) => arr.find(car => car.mark == mark) || 'car was sold'`

Comment: @user11299053 - Sure, there are a dozen spins you can put on it. Not all function declarations should be changed to expressions, note.

Comment: The point of the comment was: if you go ES6, why would you stop half way through? If you can achieve something with one line of code, you don't need to write three.

Comment: @user11299053 - Saving to a variable makes debugging easier, for one thing. But again, there are a dozen spins you can put on it.